# declaration function pointer and initialization c++

Tags: c++

**public declaration function pointer in superclass A**

```
typedef std::function<void(argument)> NamePointer;
```

**B : public A**

```
using typename A::NamePointer;
```

**main**

```
NamePointer pointer;
pointer = function;
```

this implementation of main is not correct. Why Namepointer is not seen, how do I make it visible in the main? you have to write Vector::Namepointer?. This hypothesis has not worked at the moment, can you help me?

Comment: `std::function<void(argument)>` is not a function pointer.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] instead of a vague description of your code.